# Object in mule's registry cannot be cast to org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct on application startup

Tags: mule

I'm trying to store instance of some class in mule registry on flow application startup. Below you can see my java code and flow fragment. My problem is that **sometimes** application deployment fails with following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.test.sorter.model.Config cannot be cast to org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct
    at org.mule.module.management.mbean.FlowConstructService.postRegister(FlowConstructService.java:139)
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.ClassloaderSwitchingMBeanWrapper.postRegister(ClassloaderSwitchingMBeanWrapper.java:101)
```

You can find whole stacktrace below. I must repeat: this exception is raised only sometimes, approximately every fifth deployment of unchanged application. In most cases application runs perfectly fine. I googled for this exceptions and classes but I didn't find any solution. I am using Mule 3.2.1 (standalone). Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "config")
public class Config  {
    private String x2Regex;
    private String x3Regex;
    private String x2QueueName;
    private String x3QueueName;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Initializer implements
    MuleContextNotificationListener<MuleContextNotification> {
    @Override
    public void onNotification(MuleContextNotification notification) {
        if (notification.getAction() == MuleContextNotification.CONTEXT_STARTED) {
            try {
                notification.getMuleContext().getRegistry().registerObject("config", new Config());
            } catch (RegistrationException e) {
                // cut
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<notifications>  
    <notification event="CONTEXT"/>  
    <notification-listener ref="Initializer"/> 
</notifications>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="Initializer" name="Initializer" class="com.company.test.sorter.Initializer" doc:name="Bean"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Below is fragment of mule's log with exception:

```
+ Failed to deploy app 'number-sorter', see below          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy application [number-sorter]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:68)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.start(DeploymentService.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:56)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
Caused by: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: MBeans Failed to initialise
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent$MuleContextStartedListener.onNotification(JmxAgent.java:707)
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent$MuleContextStartedListener.onNotification(JmxAgent.java:685)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:40)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:122)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:244)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:197)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:404)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:226)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:146)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:52)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: RuntimeException thrown in postRegister method
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.postRegisterInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent.registerFlowConstructServices(JmxAgent.java:428)
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent$MuleContextStartedListener.onNotification(JmxAgent.java:700)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.test.sorter.model.Config cannot be cast to org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct
    at org.mule.module.management.mbean.FlowConstructService.postRegister(FlowConstructService.java:139)
    at org.mule.module.management.agent.ClassloaderSwitchingMBeanWrapper.postRegister(ClassloaderSwitchingMBeanWrapper.java:101)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like a bug: after reading the source code, I find no reasonable explanation to why Mule would try to register your custom object in JMX while mistaking it for a Flow!

As a side note, why using a notification listener and the Mule registry when you can just build your object with Spring?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've submitted a bug: mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6225.

Comment: I've changed my app, it is not using Mule registry anymore. Thanks for suggestion.